# PHP Passing two id in the URL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to pass two ID to delete a record. The first ID that will be pass is the ID of the history record of the patient to delete. The second ID is the Primary ID of the patient foreign key to the table of history records. Once I deleted the history record of the patient it will redirect back to the profile of that patient.

Here is the code in in my table action:

```
<td><a class="text-danger" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to clear this record?')" href="clear_records.php?id=<?php print $rows4['id'];?>?p_id=<?php print $rows5['p_id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-times text-danger"></i>Clear</a></td>
```

and here is the code in **clear_records.php**

```
<?php
include "../config.php";

$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$p_id = $_REQUEST['p_id'];
// sql to delete a record
$sql = "DELETE FROM nutritional_records WHERE id=$id";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    header("location: preschooler_profile.php?p_id=$p_id");
} else {
    echo "Error Clearing record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close(); 
?>
```

This is the error:

> Error Clearing record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '?p_id=00023' at line 1

and here is my url looks like:

http://localhost/NutriCare/admin/clear_records.php?id=8?p_id=00023

Looking for help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Query parameters are joined with an ampersand in the url.  So in your html: `destination.php?foo=8&amp;bar=23`.  Currently your id is being submitted with a value of: `8?p_id=00023`, and the database expects an integer.

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: @Progrock it already worked. But that value of the p_id didn't passed in the url that it should be.

Comment: @JayzdeVera That's what he meant. You're not adding `p_id` in the correct way. Change `?p_id=<?php print $rows5['p_id']; ?>` to `&p_id=<?php print $rows5['p_id']; ?>`, (changing the `?` to `&`).

Comment: Thankyou! It worked! Never heard of that. Now I know! Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: I know you are using javascript as a prompt, but you shouldn't use a link (HTTP GET) for deletion.  Robots/browsers can follow these links, perhaps  with a pre-emptive fetch, and before you know it your data is gone.  'GET's should not have side effects.

Comment: Ohh okay so it is better to use a form for deletion? @Progrock

Comment: You can use a html form with the POST method.  And/or use javascript to create a HTTP DELETE request, and handle either or both appropriately.  Check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];` in your Php code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `URL` should look like this-

```
http://localhost/NutriCare/admin/ClearRecords.php?id=8&p_id=00023
```

There should be an ampersand(&) after your first parameter in URL and not Question mark.

Comment: The url is fine as is.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in  your code:

`<td><a class="text-danger" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to clear this record?')" href="clear_records.php?id=<?php echo $rows4['id'];?>&p_id=<?php echo $rows5['p_id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-times text-danger"></i>Clear</a></td>`

```
include "../config.php";
$id = $_GET['id'];
$p_id = $_GET['p_id'];
if(is_int($id)){
    $id = intval($id);
    $sql = "DELETE FROM nutritional_records WHERE id=$id";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        header("location: preschooler_profile.php?p_id=$p_id");
    } else {
        echo "Error Clearing record: " . $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
} else {
    echo "Invalid ID";
}
```

Comment: That won't work since, as stated in comments and in the other answer, the OP is sending the values wrong in the URL.

Comment: You should also _explain_ why the OP should try this code. What have you changed and how does it solve the issue?

Comment: @Bismarck this code will always echo 'Invalid ID', as `is_int()` with a string as an input will always evaluate to false.  Did you test your code?